# How to a split string into different values?

Tags: python, list, file, split

I have:

```
file=open("file.txt","r")
```

and the file is in the form:

```
apple\red\3 months
pear\green\4 months
```

how do I split the file so it becomes in the form of a list:

```
fruit = ['apple', 'pear']
colour = ['red','green']
expire = ['3 months', '4 months']
```

I have absolutely no idea and would appreciate help. What I have now:

```
file = open('file.txt','r')
for i in file:
   i.readline()
   i.split('\ ')
```

don't know it this is right, but have no idea when I've split it into the form of:

```
apple
red
3 months
pear
green
4 months
```

How I make the first and every 3th row after that into a list, and the 2:th and every 3th after that and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You can split the line and add each part to a list. For example:

```
fruit = []
colour = []
expire = []

file = open('file.txt','r')
for i in file:
   fruit_, colour_, expire_ = i.split('\\')
   fruit.append(fruit_)
   colour.append(colour_)
   expire.append(expire_)
```

Comment: You could simplify to `fruit_, colour_, expire_ = i.split("\\")`, then `append` using more meaningful variable names, although this would raise an error if the line isn't as expected.

Comment: If the OP wants to add more stuff on each line, this is not very extendable.

Comment: @Scorpion_God that is true; in Python 3.x, it could be `fruit_, colour_, expire_, *_ = i.split("\\")`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I meant if the OP wants to store that data as well. If you read my solution I think you will understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that as follows:

```
s = ['apple\red\3 months', 'pear\green\4 months']

fruit = [i[0] for i.split('\\') in s]
colour = [i[1] for i.split('\\') in s]
expire = [i[2] for i.split('\\') in s]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sequence unpacking with the `.split()` method, and then add each value to their separate list. Note that backslashes are used to escape special sequences, so you have to escape the backslash with a backslash and split on `'\\'` instead.

```
>>> line = 'apple\red\3 months'
>>> line = line.split('\\')
>>> line
['apple', 'red', '3 months']
>>> fruit, colour, expire = line
>>> print(fruit, colour, expire)
apple red 3 months
```

---

When reading from files you also have to `.strip()` each line because they have newline characters at the end. Solution:

```
data = {'fruits': [], 'colours': [], 'expires': []}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fruit, colour, expire = line.strip().split('\\')
        data['fruits'].append(fruit)
        data['colours'].append(colour)
        data['expires'].append(expire)
```

Extendable version:

```
columns = ['fruits', 'colours', 'expires']
data = {c: [] for c in columns}

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip().split('\\')
        for i, c in enumerate(columns):
            data[c].append(line[i])
```

Untested one-liner:

```
with open('file.txt') as f: data = {c: d for c, *d in zip(*(['fruits', 'colours', 'expires']+[line.strip().split('\\') for line in f]))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for l in open("i.txt"):
    for m in l.split('\\'):
        print(m.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going right.

```
fruit = []
color = []
expire = []
file = open('file.txt','r')
for i in file:
       i.readline()
       f, c, exp = i.split('\\')
       fruit.append(f)
       color.append(c)
       expire.append(exp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` with `*`:

```
>>> s = r'''apple\red\3 months
pear\green\4 months'''
>>> zip(*(x.rstrip().split('\\') for x in s.splitlines()))
[('apple', 'pear'), ('red', 'green'), ('3 months', '4 months')]
```

For a file you can do something like:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    fruit, colour, expire = zip(*(line.rstrip().split('\\') for line in f))
```

`zip` returns tuples instead of lists, so you can convert them to lists using `list()`.